# How to make pandoc generate header using beamer structure instead of blocks

Tags: pandoc, beamer

How do I change the way headers below slide level are converted in LaTeX by pandoc from `{block}` environment to `\structure{}` command?

- Imagine such a Markdown file (`foo.md`)

  ```
  # Slide title

  ## Header

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
  ```
- Let us convert it to LaTeX with the following command:

  ```
  pandoc -t beamer --slide-level 1 foo.md -o foo.tex
  ```
- The resulting LaTeX file is something similar to:

  ```latex
  \begin{frame}{Slide}

  \begin{block}{Header}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

  \end{block}

  \end{frame}
  ```

Is there an easy simple and elegant solution so that pandoc produce something like the following?

```latex
\begin{frame}{Slide}

\structure{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to achieve via [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html):

```lua
function Header (header)
  if header.level == 2 then
    local inlines = pandoc.List:new{}
    inlines:extend {pandoc.RawInline('tex', '\\structure{')}
    inlines:extend(header.content)
    inlines:extend {pandoc.RawInline('tex', '}')}
    return pandoc.Plain(inlines)
  end
end
```

Safe the filter to a file and pass that file to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` option.

Comment: As you told me on Twitter I had to add `pandoc.List = require 'pandoc.List'` in the top of the filter for making it work (my pandoc version may be too old : 2.2.1). Thank's a lot this solution is very nice and elegant :-)